# Hitachi S3 API (HCP): Modify existing Object with HTTP PUT

Tags: java, amazon-s3, http-put

I'm using the AmazonS3 Client in my Java Application to store objects in our Storage which is from Hitachi and has an S3 API. `putObject()` does save the object correctly, but when i'm trying to modify the existinf object by using the identical body and object-ID, I get this exception:

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Object already exists. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 409; Error Code: OperationAborted; Request ID: 1622623300123; S3 Extended Request ID: ZzEwLXByaS5hZC5kcmd1ZWxkZW5lci5kZToxMDI=), S3 Extended Request ID: ZzEwLXByaS5hZC5kcmd1ZWxkZW5lci5kZToxMDI="

This is how my request looks like:

```
private PutObjectRequest buildPutObjectRequest(String id, StorageObject storageObject, String currentBucket) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(storageObject);
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(json.length());

    return new PutObjectRequest(currentBucket, id, new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()), metadata);
}
```

Normally I'd expect to update the existing object using a PUT-Request. The documentation tells me that with versioning enabled a copy will be created but that's not what I want to do. Do you guys have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling versioning is indeed the only way we have found to "overwrite" an object on HCP. In our tests enabling versioning did not appear to have any other unwanted side-effect. You can set a very short retention time to ensure few(er) versions are kept.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've accepted versioning as the only solution. It works fine even if it is not the solution i wanted. Another way would be checking if the object already exists to delete it before creating again. Well, that would be more of a workaround.